# How to use Rolle's Theorem or the Mean Value Theorem to prove particular intersection points are the only intersection points

Tags: calculus

$$f(x) = x^{3}$$ and $$g(x) = \sqrt{x}$$
Find all of the intersection points between the graphs of $f$ and $g$. Show that these are the only intersection points

I have found the intersection points which are $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ but how can I apply **Rolle's Theorem** or the **Mean Value Theorem** to prove that they are the only intersection points? Any hints for this question?

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to look for smarter approaches: have you noticed that $f(x)=g(x)$ is equivalent to $x(x^5-1)=0$ with the constraint $x \geq 0$?

Comment: How can I apply the mean value theorem? This method seems to solve for x by basic calculus, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $h=f-g$. We have that $h(0)=h(1)=0$. Suppose that there is another root let's say $a\in \Bbb R$. Then $a\in (0,1)$ or $a\in(-\infty,0)$ or $a\in (1,\infty)$. Let's say that $a\in(0,1)$ then applying Rolle's Theorem we have that $h'$ has at least two roots,one in $(0,a)$ and one in $(a,1)$. But then  $$h''(x)=6x+\frac {1}{4\sqrt[3/2] {x}}$$ has one root in  $(0,1)$ which is not true. So for $h$, we have at most two roots and at least two roots when you found them. Thus we have two roots only.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider the function $h(x) = f(x) - g(x) $. You are looking for points where $h(x) = 0 $

Comment: Yes, I have tried to do the same thing but are there any way to solve this by mean value theorem?

Answer (score 0):

There are two intersection points: $x_0=0$ and $x_1=1$. Assume that $f(x_2)=g(x_2)$ for some $x_0 < x_2 < x_1$. By the theorem of Lagrange, there exist $c_1 \in (x_0,x_2)$ and $c_2 \in (x_2,x_1)$ with
$$
f'(c_1)=g'(c_1), \quad f'(c_2)=g'(c_2).
$$
But $f'(\xi)=g'(\xi)$ means $\xi^{5/2}=\frac{1}{6}$, and this equation has only one positive root. Contradiction!